# Make forked process execute in a fixed order

Tags: posix, ipc, shared-memory

I was asked to make forked process execute in a fixed order coding in c/c++
(for example parent->chile->parent)
To execute the parents first after forking and then execute the child and finally return to the parents.

Only shared memory can be used.
Other IPCs, similar ones to mutex or Semaphores are not allowed.
for loop or sleep() is forbidden too.

Is there a way to make it work?

```
        open_my_shm();


    if (fork()==0) {
        //The parents code needs to be executed first
        sleep(3);   //sleep is strictly forbidden so I'm looking for 
 another option
        
        //child code here
                    
        exit(0);
    }
    else {

         //parent code here  
         //The parents code needs to be executed first
         //then go to child
         wait(&status);
        //parent code here
        }


        close_shm();
```

I have tried the sleep function
it works well but is not allowed

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: The most straightforward way to do it through memory without sleeping functions is by having the child loop until the parent flips a shared-memory-placed atomic variable. The restriction on `for` loops seems weird given that it's by no means the only way to loop.

Comment: POSIX processes are designed to send signals to parent processes when the children terminate not the other way around. There's definitely a way to do what you describe, but it's going to feel hacky at best. Are you sure you don't have the problem backwards?

Comment: You can use the shared memory to signal between the processes but this is going to involve busy-waiting which completely defeats the purpose of process synchronization, and all the memory will have to be treated at `volatile` and if atomics are not available on your system you're going to have race conditions

Answer (score 0):

`sleep()` appears to be working because it asks the operating system not to schedule the calling process for a given amount of time. This is "working" because your operating system is pretty good at scheduling processes efficiently, and it just so happens that the amount of time you asked the process to `sleep()` for is long enough for your parent process to finish. This is a coincidence, however. There is nothing about a call to `sleep()` that will force the child process to wait until the parent is finished before continuing execution because the call has nothing to do with inter-process synchronization.

`POSIX` processes have built-in mechanisms to signal the parent when a child process terminates, but the opposite is not true. If you're using a Linux system, you can use `prctl()` and the argument `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` to cause the child to receive a signal of your choice when its parent dies, which you could then call `sigwait()` in the child process to wait for. However if you're going to go to the trouble of using signals, you could also just `raise(SIGSTOP)` in the child process, then send a signal to the child from the parent like `kill(pid, SIGCONT);` (where `pid` is the nonzero return value of `fork()`) once its work is done, however if the parent does not first wait to be notified that the child has been stopped via `waitpid(pid,&status,WUNTRACED)` this may cause a race-condition in the case that the parent is ready for the child to continue before it has processed the `SIGSTOP` it has sent itself.

If you don't want to or aren't allowed to use signals, the parent could write a value in the shared memory before `fork()`ing, then the child could check it over and over in a loop until the parent changes it, which would be the child's signal to move on, but this wastes a lot of processor resources, and could cause race conditions or bugs if the shared memory location you use is not `_Atomic`, or if it is not treated as `volatile`, or if the shared memory is not properly mapped so that standard copy-on-write behavior is not followed as is the usual after `fork()`.

This is a very odd question and a difficult problem to solve, because `fork()`, `waitpid()`, and all the other process synchronization functions in POSIX based systems are not designed to work this way. If you have a task that should be done by a child process, but there is something that the parent must do before the child begins to work, then it only makes sense to wait to call `fork()` until **after** the parent is done with its before-child duties, rather than `fork()` and tell the child to hold on for a moment.

This problem becomes trivial if you just flip the duties of the parent and child, for instance:

```
    open_my_shm();

    if (fork()==0) {
        //child code here (This will be executed first)
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
         wait(&status); //Parent will wait for child to terminate
        //parent code here (...then this will execute)
    }
    close_shm();
```

...which I suspect is the intended solution of the problem, otherwise this is a very odd assignment indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice I have learned a lot
I was asked to use shared memory to pass the child pid to the child so it seems I have no choice.

Comment: It seems to me that the `raise(SIGSTOP)` is race-prone unless the parent will `waitpid(..., WUNTRACED)` to know that the child is stopped, before generating the SIGCONT.

Comment: I have edited the body of my answer; good catch!

Comment: @mumei Opening a shared memory region and carefully avoiding race conditions without the help of inter-process semaphores just to pass the child's PID to it rather than just having the child call `getpid()` seems like a lot of work... are you sure that's what your prof intended?